# Bootstrap Modal showing with Transparent Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[image]

I am using bootstrap modal that i am showing on ajax success call.
I have 2 issues.
1) All the contents are showing and working but the form fields looks not focused as it happens in normal modal.

2) the regex not applying in the form field ?

Where is the issue?

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regx",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);



                $(function (){
                //validation rules
                $("#signup_form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        "name": {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 5,
                            regx: /^[a-zA-Z]$/ 
                        },  

     submitHandler: function() {
      $.post('form_process.php', 
     $('form#signup_form').serialize() , 
    function(){
       $("#myModal1").modal('show');
    $('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#email').focus();
    });
```

Html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="modal" id="myModal1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content"> <!--This should be preset-->
    <div class="modal-header">
 <!--  
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Not Now</button>
-->
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      -->
        <h3>Login to Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="">
          <div class="">
          <div id="modalTab">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="login">
                <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
                  <p>
                    <input type="text"  name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="password"  name="passwd" placeholder="Password">
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                    <a href="#forgotpassword" data-toggle="tab">Forgot Password?</a>
                  </p>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="forgotpassword">
                <form method="post" action='' name="forgot_password">
                  <p>Hey this stuff happens, send us your email and we'll reset it for you!</p>
                  <input type="text" class="span12" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Wait, I remember it now!</a>
                  </p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="mainPage.php" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Not now!</a>
        </div>


  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your `css` for `modal` pls.. have you modified it???

Comment: @GuruprasadRao
Nope, i just copied it from somewhere.

Comment: Jus inspect `modal-body` and see what styles have been shown with that..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao
On inspection, i found that the modal-body has css
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}

Comment: @GuruprasadRao
Oh yes !
It's getting color...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao
But on giving white color, The form fields are not displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed to add `modal-content` and wrap the `modal-header` and `modal-body` into it.. `modal-content` is the one which contains `style` `background-color`. Below would be your changes.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-content"> <!--This should be preset-->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h3>Login to Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
          <div id="modalTab">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="login">
                <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" class="span12" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="password" class="span12" name="passwd" placeholder="Password">
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                    <a href="#forgotpassword" data-toggle="tab">Forgot Password?</a>
                  </p>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="forgotpassword">
                <form method="post" action='' name="forgot_password">
                  <p>Hey this stuff happens, send us your email and we'll reset it for you!</p>
                  <input type="text" class="span12" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Wait, I remember it now!</a>
                  </p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Background color started to appear now 1
But the form fields are not showing, only the placeholder value is displaying ........

Comment: Inspect the `textbox` style in browser, or try to create a `DEMO`! Post a screenshot too if possible..

Comment: ok you solved my second issue instead - the regex issue- i posted in my question

Comment: Lol, you posted it now.. Am confused now.. :)

Comment: No dude!
Is it really a problem for you ;)

Comment: Nope, I don't have any problem.. ;)

Comment: then do it, it will save my time dear.

Comment: Ok, let me ask again, you've issue with textbox now? Like style issues?

Comment: No dear, in my question read my second problem regarding regex. i am talking about that ...

Comment: Then you said I solved it - _ok you solved my second issue instead_ in your previous comments..

Comment: Try adding that `regex` inside `post` once the `modal loads`

Comment: Oh sorry, that was my mistake.
i am applying this regex to a simple signup form not at the modal form.

Comment: so, what should i do and how?
Any idea?

Comment: Don't have much idea on `validations plugin`. I would suggest that you visit their site and see how you can do it..